# Include a whole directory of *.lib with msvc compiler?

Tags: visual-c++, linker, cl.exe

I have typed out a fairly long commands to get my program to compile. This is it:

```
C:\Users\Sevbomb\Desktop\MSVC>Bin\cl.exe /I Includes\Winsdk helloworldgui.c Libs
\Uuid.lib Libs\libcmt.lib Libs\oldnames.lib Libs\Kernel32.Lib Libs\User32.Lib Li
bs\Gdi32.Lib Libs\WinMM.Lib
```

Instead of passing all those filenames to the linker, can I just tell it to look in a directory for any libraries it might need?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question???

Comment: Instead of including all those *.lib files individually, as shown above, I was wondering if I could just include the directory. Because they are all in the same directory.